# Buildozer says ndk not up to date, when I put up to date ndk in the android directory, can't recognize it

Tags: android, android-ndk, kivy, apk, buildozer

So I'm trying to compile an apk file on mac using kivy, whenever I use the command buildozer android debug, it says NDK not found but then it downloads an NDK for itself but it is version 17c, then it itself shows an error message saying that 'Build failed: minimum supported NDK version is 19" here's the whole error-

```
[ERROR]:   Build failed: The minimum supported NDK version is 19. You can download it from https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/.
[INFO]:    Instructions: Please, go to the android NDK page (https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/) and download a supported version.
*** The currently recommended NDK version is 19b ***
# Command failed: /Users/saqlainsajid/opt/anaconda3/envs/gen-37/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=boringapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/saqlainsajid/PycharmProjects/.buildozer/android/platform/build" --ndk-api=21
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     LANG = 'en_CA.UTF-8'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.87vhUoS8kJ/Listeners'
#     HOME = '/Users/saqlainsajid'
#     PATH = '/Users/saqlainsajid/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/Users/saqlainsajid/opt/anaconda3/envs/gen-37/bin:/Users/saqlainsajid/opt/anaconda3/condabin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin'
#     MAIL = '/var/mail/root'
#     LOGNAME = 'root'
#     USER = 'root'
#     SHELL = '/bin/sh'
#     SUDO_COMMAND = '/Users/saqlainsajid/opt/anaconda3/envs/gen-37/bin/buildozer android debug'
#     SUDO_USER = 'saqlainsajid'
#     SUDO_UID = '502'
#     SUDO_GID = '20'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/Users/saqlainsajid/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/Users/saqlainsajid/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/Users/saqlainsajid/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r17c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

I tried to download the latest android NDK and unzip it in /Users/saqlainsajid/.buildozer/android/platform

doesn't work

what do I do?

Answer (score 1):

outdated NDK won't work.. The latest version could be found on here(https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads) , download and unzipped it into a named directory and to prevent all time download, specify the directory where the unzipped NDK inside your **buildozer.spec*** file under `NDK_DIRECTORY`